# scroll to the next div on button click

Tags: jquery, html, scrolltop

I am building a website which has a div in the right bottom corner. This is alwaays visible and floating no matter how far up or down you scroll. Once you click it it should scroll down to the next div though. The website is one long scrolling page site. There are 5 divs which are stacked on top of each other. How can I achieve this? I am using JQuery and scrollTop to try to make this happen but it is not working. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you provide the code in text format? its hard to parse an image...

Comment: You should use `<a name="">` elements to force focus on a page position, no javascript needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this by giving each `<div>` an ID, and making the `<div>` in the bottom right contain an `<a>` with the default href being `href='#<firstdiv>'`. From there, you can put each `<div>` ID in an array and cycle through them onclick. So your bottom right div would look like this

```
<div><a onclick="cycle(this);" href="#first_div"></a></div>
```

Your individual `<div>`s that you're jumping to would look like this

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="third"></div>
```

And your JS would be this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var divs = ["first", "second", "third"];
    var counter = 0;
});

function cycle(element) {
    $(element).attr("href", divs[counter]);
    if(counter < divs.length - 1) {
        counter++;
    }
    else {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

While not the most modular way of approaching the problem, this should provide a reasonably simple solution.

Comment: Hi @Gladdstone Thank you for that answer. It is saying divs is not defined. Could you provide a js fiddle by any chance?

Comment: Sorry about that, I defined the variable in the document.ready function, just move the declarations for "divs" and "counter" outside where you would put any other global variable.

Or you could put the cycle function INSIDE the document.ready function, which should also work to put the variables within scope.

Comment: Thank you so much! I moved it ouside! It works perfectly! Is there anyway to animate the jump to the next div to where it is scrolling down by any chance?

Comment: Google "smooth scrolling" and you'll find a couple good resources. Very easy to implement in jQuery.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will do that! I appreciate all the help! :)